# Does hibernate search - 6.0 version support projection on embedded entities?

Tags: hibernate-search

I am developing a search api where I need to return in response the resource with only the fields/properties asked in request. The fields can be of sub elements as well. E.g - *book.author.name* where *book* is the parent resource and *author* a sub resource under it, may be with a many to one relationship.
I have learned in earlier versions of hibernate (5.x.x) projections is not supported on embedded entities.
So wanted to know if this feature is added in 6.0

Answer (score 0):

When there is a single author, yes, you can do a projection on the author (but you could already in Search 5, though in a less convenient way):

```java
@Entity
@Indexed
class Book {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @GenericField
    private String title;
    @ManyToOne
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private Author author;

    // ...getters and setters...
}

@Entity
class Author {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @GenericField(projectable = Projectable.YES)
    private String firstName;
    @GenericField(projectable = Projectable.YES)
    private String lastName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

    // ...getters and setters...
}

class MyProjectedAuthor {
    public final String firstName;
    public final String lastName;

    public MyProjectedAuthor(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}

SearchSession searchSession = Search.session(entityManager);
List<MyProjectedAuthor> projectedAuthors = searchSession.search(Book.class)
        .asProjection(f -> f.composite(
                MyProjectedAuthor::new,
                f.field("author.firstName", String.class),
                f.field("author.lastName", String.class),
        ))
        .predicate(f -> f.matchAll())
        .fetchHits(20);
```

Multi-valued projections (e.g. if you have multiple authors per book) are not supported yet, but we will be working on it before the 6.0.0 release: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3391

If you were talking about *loading* the authors from the database instead of projections, then there is no such built-in feature yet. We'll be looking into it when we address [HSEARCH-3071](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3071), but I can't tell how long it will take.

As a workaround, for single-valued associations, you can implement loading manually:

```java
@Entity
@Indexed
class Book {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @GenericField
    private String title;
    @ManyToOne
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private Author author;

    // ...getters and setters...
}

@Entity
class Author {
    @Id
    @GenericField(projectable = Projectable.YES)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

    // ...getters and setters...
}

SearchSession searchSession = Search.session(entityManager);
List<Author> authors = searchSession.search(Book.class)
        .asProjection(f -> f.composite(
                authorId -> entityManager.getReference(Author.class, authorId),
                f.field("author.id", Long.class)
        ))
        .predicate(f -> f.matchAll())
        .fetchHits(20);

// Or, for more efficient loading:
SearchSession searchSession = Search.session(entityManager);
List<Long> authorIds = searchSession.search(Book.class)
        .asProjection(f -> f.field("author.id", Long.class))
        .predicate(f -> f.matchAll())
        .fetchHits(20);
List<Author> authors = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).byMultipleIds(Author.class)
        .withBatchSize(20)
        .multiLoad(authorIds);
```

**EDIT**: According to your comment, your problem was related to many fields, not just the author. Essentially, you are concerned about loading as few associations as possible.

The most common solution to this problem in Hibernate ORM is to set all your associations' fetch mode to lazy (which is what you should do by default, anyway).
Then when searching, do not even think about loading: just ask Hibernate Search to retrieve the entities you need. Associations will not be loaded at that point.
Then, when you serialize your entities to JSON, only the associations you actually use will be loaded. If you correctly set the default batch fetch size (with `hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size`, [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-database-fetch), performance should be comparable to what you'll achieve with more complicated solutions, at a fraction of the development time.

If you really want to fetch some of the associations eagerly, the easiest solution would probably be to leverage JPA's entity graphs: they tell Hibernate ORM which associations to load exactly when it loads the Book entity.

There's no built-in functionnality for that in Hibernate Search 6 [yet](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3628), but you can do it manually:

```java
@Entity
@Indexed
class Book {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @GenericField
    private String title;
    @ManyToOne // No need for an @IndexedEmbedded with this solution, at least not for loading
    private Author author;

    // ...getters and setters...
}

@Entity
class Author {
    @Id // No need for an indexed ID with this solution, at least not for loading
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

    // ...getters and setters...
}

SearchSession searchSession = Search.session(entityManager);
List<Long> bookIds = searchSession.search(Book.class)
        .asProjection(f -> f.composite(ref -> (Long)ref.getId(), f.entityReference()))
        .predicate(f -> f.matchAll())
        .fetchHits(20);

// Note: there are many ways to build a graph, some less verbose than this one.
// See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-strategies-dynamic-fetching-entity-graph
javax.persistence.EntityGraph<Book> graph = entityManager.createEntityGraph( Book.class );
graph.addAttributeNode( "author" );
// Ask for the author association to be loaded eagerly
graph.addSubgraph( "author" ).addAttributeNode( "name" );

List<Book> booksWithOnlySomeAssociationsFetched = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).byMultipleIds(Book.class)
        .with(graph, org.hibernate.graph.GraphSemantic.FETCH)
        .withBatchSize(20)
        .multiLoad(bookIds);
```

Note that, even with this solution, you should probably set the fetch mode to lazy in the mapping (@OnyToMany, ...) for as many associations as possible, because Hibernate ORM [doesn't allow making an eager association lazy though a fetch graph](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8776).

Comment: I have a large number of sub entities and many fields over which I have to apply field filtering. So above solution in 5 is less convenient for me. Now a days best practices on REST api development mandates fields on search apis as client do not require always all the fields and some times the resource data is so big that it can impact the application performance and bandwidth returning the whole resource data back.

Comment: @Retheesh Added some more content to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, will have to try it out to select an optimal one.